# Outside air unit

Tags: air-conditioning

Replaced the capacitor on outside unit. It will run for about 30 mins and works fine then the fan will stop turning but it sounds like the motor is still on but the motor feels hot. Would the motor overheating cause the fan to stop turning?

The fan still turns freely though.

Sometimes I can just take a screwdriver and give the fan a lil spin and it will start back up but after 15 20 mins it will stop again.

Comment: Was the capacitor replaced for this problem or for a different problem?

Comment: For this problem. Thought that would fix it but it didn’t. The top of gets real hot like motor is overheating then the fan will stop turning

Comment: did you use OEM part

Comment: fan bearings would do that overheat after a while, is the fan hard to turn after it stops ??  >>>try some oil

Comment: I had a motor give up, the bearings siezed and it was hard to turn manually (with the power off, of course). This pulls extra electricity and can blow fuses, make the fan motor hot, and other behaviors. I replaced the fan motor at the same time as the run capacitor, it ran like normal again.

Comment: When the fan stops turning but keeps making sound, if you then turn off the A/C and try to spin the fan, does it spin freely? (You can use a chop stick to move the blades.) Or does it stop when you stop pushing it?

Comment: MTA. It spins freely

Comment: Please [edit] to include the brand/model # of the unit and all the specs on the replacement capacitor. It's possible that you used the wrong one. It could also be something else, entirely, but knowing those details will help.